# Remove white space from params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strip

I have a piece of code which collects params from a form and reads them into invite as I can see. The problem is one of these parameters is an email which I want to ensure has no trailing whitespace. How could I apply strip to invite and all of the params fed into it?

```
def invite_partner
  return unless invite = params[:partner]
  return flash.now[:error] = 'Please select a role' unless role = Role.where(klass: invite[:klass], name: 'Admin').first
  return flash.now[:alert] = 'Email address already in use' if User.where(email: invite[:email]).first

  raise 'bugger' unless current_user.is_a?(User)

  partner_invite = PartnerInviteMailer.invite(current_user.operator, invite[:email], invite[:klass], Portal.portal_for_hostname(host_from_request))
  partner_invite.deliver

  flash.now[:success] = "#{invite[:klass]} invited, email sent to #{invite[:email]}"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

```
params[:partner].each { |key, value| value.strip! }
```

Comment: I get `undefined method `strip!' for ["contact_name", "Eamonn"]:Array` when I attempt this. I had thought this would be the approach originally but no such luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are all the params arrays?

Comment: Here is a sample of what I am trying to strip: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pBVKk9Aa7540buWSQrPO0pomC8LQCCFIlrel+ocjJRI=", "partner"=>{"contact_name"=>"Eamonn", "company_name"=>"Eamonn", "email"=>"eamonn.mcelroy@email.com         ", "company_notes"=>"ew", "klass"=>"Partner"}, "commit"=>"Send Invite"}` It doesnt show it but the email has a lot of trailing spaces which I need removed.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Forgot about the difference between array and hash etc. On another note can I ensure the strip is retained in the actual object as I ran this and the spaces remain.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by 'ensure the strip is retained in the actual object'

Answer (score 1):

Skip array's like related ids.

```
params[:partner].each { |key, value| value.strip! unless value.kind_of?(Array) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `try` method, which will handle Arrays, `nil` values, etc without having to check `kind_of?`.

```
params[:partner].each { |key, value| value.try(:strip!) }
```